# USB modem could not mount on 12.04

Tags: 12.04, mount, usb-modem

I have a usb wimax modem. If I connect it at ubuntu 10.04 it has been detected and mounted as cd [see here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/50794756@N06/7891741842/in/photostream).

From there I got that it is "iso96660" type and device location is `/dev/sr1`.

But when I connect this usb modem in Ubuntu 12.04, it could not be mounted. So I have tried to find the file `sr1` in this location `/dev/` and could not found any-thing. But if disconnect and then re-connect the usb modem at this path `/dev/`, I saw a flickering of "sr1" named file for a certain time (1 sec) then it's dis-appear.

Can anyone guide me to connect it step-by-step in Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: Edit the question to add the output of `lsusb` and also the model and made of your wimax modem

Answer (score 2):

Newer USB modems specially Wimax modems use a feature called [zero cd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_CD-ROM_switching_utility#ZeroCD). When you first insert the device, it will act as a CDROM and the driver gets installed from that CDROM. On subsequent insertion, the modem first mounted as CDROM and then very quickly it switched to the **Modem mode**, when the system detects the available driver.

Quoting from [Wikipedia Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_CD-ROM_switching_utility#ZeroCD):

> When a device uses the ZeroCD method means that it behaves as a USB CD-ROM when first connected, with a virtual CD-ROM inserted with the Windows device drivers and related Cosmote control program. Once the Windows device drivers are installed, a special USB command is sent to the device to “switch” it to modem mod

The package which is responsible to do the switching to the proper mode in Ubuntu is [usb-modeswitch](http://www.draisberghof.de/usb_modeswitch/#intro). So, Ubuntu 12.04 successfully switched the modem from CDROM mode to modem mode, which is required to use that as a modem.

#### Then why 10.04 mounts that as CDROM?

I guess, the `usb-modeswitch` package installed on Ubuntu 10.04 was missing the proper switching configuration for your specific Modem. *(Please note that, proper configuration is required to do switch, such as `vendor_id`, `product_id` etc.)*. So, it only mounts it as a CDROM and can't go further.

If you are interested to see the content of the Modem device in *CDROM* mode, you have to prevent switching. *(I'll add more info on this topic, if I find them)*. But, if you want to use the device as Modem, I think, you need to setup a connection using your modem now as it is already detected as modem.

#### If you want to mount the CDROM mode of the modem

1. First remove the USB Modem
2. Use this command to prevent `usb_modeswitch` to automatically switch to Wimax mode upon insertion.

   ```
   sudo chmod -x /usr/sbin/usb_modeswitch
   ```
3. Then remove the driver if already activated. For my device (it is ZTE AX226 from Banglalion) the driver is `bcm_wimax`. So, I removed it with command:

   ```
   sudo modprobe -r bcm_wimax
   ```

   The drive may not be the same as me, but You can see a list of drivers loaded by the OS with command `lsmod`.
4. Then execute `lsblk` command to see the CDROM mode of the device and it's device name. Alternatively you can use *Disk-utility* tool. For me it is `/dev/sr1`.
5. Then use `udisks` or Disk-utility to mount the device.

   ```
   udisks --mount /dev/sr1
   ```

   If will be mounted most probably in `/media/disk` folder.
6. Do what you wanted to do with it.
7. Then again re-enable the `usb_modeswitch` with this command: **(
   This step is important)**

   ```
   sudo chmod +x /usr/sbin/usb_modeswitch
   ```

Comment: thanks for your reply. What you have describe i know that but again thanks to remind me.When i connect that modem in ubuntu 10.04 it's appear in that [way](http://www.flickr.com/photos/50794756@N06/7896163846/in/photostream/lightbox/). I want the same thing in ubuntu 12.04. So, how can i do that???

Comment: @maz I've added instruction to mount the modem as CDROM also. Please check the answer

Comment: many many thanks for your answer. Anwar i modem is "Qubee" provided "shuttle" modem. It's not linux compatible because it's pre-loaded with windows driver. Now came up with your instruction. At first in my ubuntu 12.04 there is no usb_modeswitch installed. Secondly no driver is installed. But i have use your "lsblk" command and got this out-put.

Comment: here is the [out-put](http://www.flickr.com/photos/50794756@N06/7902502928/in/photostream/lightbox/)

Comment: from this out-put you can see there is no "sr1" device is present. When i connect the device in usb for a short period of time the file "sr1" could be found in "/dev" folder. And then vanish. I hope you can guide me to the right path. Thanks in advance

Comment: @maz I think, i've already told you what to do. disable the `usb_modeswitch` and then reconnect device. Please see my answer

Comment: @Anwar thanks a lot. It's work. Actually usb_modeswitch was present but i could found it from ubuntu software center instead i have browse the location "/usr/sbin/" and found there. Really appreciate your help. Thanks again.